# The Aeneid “facilis descensus averno” or “facilis descensus averni”

Tags: classical-latin, motto, aeneis

I’m getting a tattoo of the line from the Aeneid “The descent into hell is easy” and wasn’t sure if it is “fascilis descensus averno” or “fascilis descensus averni”. Which one is it? What’s the difference?

Comment: Hi Tucker! If you want to continue using this site, I recommend registering an account. That would allow you to get notifications and otherwise access your own posts. With the reputation gained from this question, you can vote the questions and answers you like. If you can't access your old unregistered account, create a new one (from the same place if possible) and raise a flag for moderators, and the two accounts can be combined.

Answer (score 3):

I checked [Perseus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0055%3Abook%3D6%3Acard%3D124) and [The Latin Library](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/vergil/aen6.shtml).
Both use *facilis descensus Averno*.
You misspelled *facilis* ("easy"); it is not related to *fascis*.
Did you find the version *Averni* somewhere?

Anyway, both forms make sense.
I would read *descensus Averno* as "descent through the entrance of the underworld" and *descensus Averni* as "descent of the entrance of the underworld".
The word [*Avernus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DA%3Aentry+group%3D94%3Aentry%3DAvernus) actually means literally "birdless" and refers to a place considered to be an entrance to the underworld.
It does not mean "hell" directly, but by metonymy it makes sense to say that *descensus Averni/Averno* is "descent to hell".

I would recommend *facilis descensus Averno*.
As I said, the difference to *Averni* is insignificant, but I wouldn't use that before finding it in an edition of the Aeneid.
[As noted in the comments, there are editions with *Averni*, but *Averno* seems to be preferred. Both are valid choices.]

Comment: "Averni" is a variant reading in some manuscripts of the Aeneid, but "Averno" is favoured by modern editors, surely for some good reason that I am not able to investigate at the moment.

Comment: The most recent Teubner edition (2011, ed. Gian Biagio Conte) also has "facilis descensus Auerno"

Comment: Google Books search gives 13,800 results for "facilis descensus Averni" and 7,320 results for "facilis descensus Averno". Not implying anyone is wrong or anything, just found this data interesting in itself.

Comment: @Rodia That's interesting to know. The way I see those results is that the two versions are equally common (as Google hits). Typically when you compare two things that way, one is bigger not by a factor of two but ten or thousand or million.

Comment: Sometimes quantity is less important than quality. No one is trying to imply that Averni is non-existent; however, all the major scholarly editions of Aeneis of the twentieth and twenty first centuries are clear on this matter - the preferred choice is "Averno". The most recent Teubner edition (2011, ed. Gian Biagio Conte, not Conti - mea culpa) says: auerno **MPbnrx,** *schol. Bern. ad buc. 5, 6, Tib.* (auerno est **M²**): auerni **P²Rωγ**; *utrumque agnoscit Seru*.

Comment: although Collinge (in [Collinge 1959](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1086972)), who I highly respected, insisted on Averni, not Averno.

Comment: I agree with you, Joonas. Both forms are expected: grammatically speaking, _Averni_ is to be analyzed as the complement of the **noun** _descensus_, whereas _Averno_ is analyzed as the complement of the **verb**al base of the noun _descensus_.  The fact that _descensus_ is a "strongly **deverbal**" noun can account for your correct observation that "_Averno_ seems to be preferred".

Comment: The phrase *facilis descensus Averni* was used by M. Auguste Dupin in Poe's *The Purloined Letter.*